# MySQL: Query to Search All possible words

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form with an input box where user can specify their names, names can be two or more words eg `John Smith` or `John Michael Smith`.

I need to write a query which would return the records including ALL words in the submitted name. So query will return records which has all those name words but can have different order.

For example, if search string is `John Michael Smith`, query should be able to return records with names such as `John Smith Michael`, `Michael Smith John`, `Smith John Michael` or other combination with all those words there. As can be seen return only records which still has all words in name field but can have different order. It should not however return results which do not contain a name part for example `John Michael` should not be returned since it is missing `Smith`.

I can't figure out how to write a query for such requirement that I have. Please help.

---

### Update

The answers provided so far return even the records that match `John Michael` also. I tried answers of [@Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752400/mysql-query-to-search-all-possible-words/7752448#7752448), [@abesto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752400/mysql-query-to-search-all-possible-words/7752510#7752510) and [@Eddie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752400/mysql-query-to-search-all-possible-words/7752485#7752485).

The problem still persists :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a fulltext search:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (name)
AGAINST ('+part1 +part2 +part3' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

In this solution, '+part1 +part2 +part3' would be generated in PHP.

See [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

```
mysql> select * from sof;
+--------------------+
| n                  |
+--------------------+
| John               |
| Smith              |
| Smith John         |
| Smith John Michael |
| John               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM sof WHERE MATCH(n) AGAINST('+John +Smith +Michael' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+--------------------+
| n                  |
+--------------------+
| Smith John Michael |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: results also include 'John Michael' :(

Comment: They should most definitely not. See the update for a test run.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE 
    name LIKE '%John%' AND 
    name LIKE '%Michael%' AND 
    name LIKE '%Smith%'
```

Obviously the `WHERE` part must be built dinamically using user input.
There is something that could be wrong, but you have to decide it: if column contains something like *"Michael Smith Johnas"* this record is returned.

Comment: Your query specifies specific order eg John first Michael second and Smith third. So i wonder whether it will work for different order of these three words also?

Comment: yes it does work for a different order - a name Michael John Smith fits the where clause as does John Smith Michael because the wildcard '%' is both before and after the names.  however, as @Marco pointed out you will also get results for names like Michaels, Johnas etc.

Comment: results also include 'John Michael' :(

Comment: @Dev555: no, it doesn't. I've just tried it and that record is not selected with my query!!!

Comment: here is how i tried it but as i said, it also returns John Michael: SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE
     name LIKE '%Michael%' &&
     name LIKE '%Smith%' &&
     name LIKE '%John%'

Comment: Can you gently send me your users table after exporting it in a SQL file? I'd like to understand what's going on, because with the same query I do not have that record in results!!!

Answer (score 1):

its quite easy dude.

```
$keyword=$_POST['keyword'];
$keywords=explode(' ',$keyword);
for($i=0;$i<count($keywords);$i++)
$where .= ($i ? ' and ' : ' where ')."`name` like '%{$keywords[$i]}% '";
$q="select * from $table ".$where;
$rs=mysql_query($q);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$keywords = explode(" ",$search);
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE songTitle LIKE '%".$keywords[0];       
  for($kw=1;$kw < count($keywords);$kw++) {
    $query .= "%".$keywords[$kw];
  }
$query .= "%' ";
//echo "query= ".$query."<br>";  // Check your query statement here
        
mysql_query($query, $connect) or die ($Error=mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$name=$_POST['name'];  //save the search query in a variable
$query = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name like %$name%";
```

Comment: if the search query will contain more than one name, use @eddie's answer above...